# Проблема с кроссбраузерностью, на firefox не работает hover после загрузки js

Tags: html, jquery, css, анимация

http://maksleskin.ru/temp/

Нашел интересную анимацию, но вот в firefox не работает, то есть анимация работает, но не работает hover, в opera и chrome все нормально. Кода много

```js
(function($) {
  // Global initialisation flag
  var initialized = false;

  // For detecting browser prefix and capabilities
  var el = document.createElement("div");
  var re = /^(Moz|(w|W)ebkit|O|ms)(?=[A-Z])/;

  // Establish vendor prefix and CSS 3D support
  var vendor =
    (function() {
      for (var p in el.style)
        if (re.test(p)) return p.match(re)[0];
    })() || "";
  var canRun = vendor + "Perspective" in el.style;
  var prefix = "-" + vendor.toLowerCase() + "-";

  var $this, $root, $base, $kids, $node, $item, $over, $back;
  var wait, anim, last;

  // Public API
  var api = {
    // Toggle open / closed
    toggle: function() {
      $this = $(this);
      $this.makisu($this.hasClass("open") ? "close" : "open");
    },

    // Trigger the unfold animation
    open: function(speed, overlap, easing) {
      // Cache DOM references
      $this = $(this);
      $root = $this.find(".root");
      $kids = $this.find(".node").not($root);

      // Establish values or fallbacks
      speed = utils.resolve($this, "speed", speed);
      easing = utils.resolve($this, "easing", easing);
      overlap = utils.resolve($this, "overlap", overlap);

      $kids.each(function(index, el) {
        // Establish settings for this iteration
        anim = "unfold" + (!index ? "-first" : "");
        last = index === $kids.length - 1;
        time = speed * (1 - overlap);
        wait = index * time;

        // Cache DOM references
        $item = $(el);
        $over = $item.find(".over");

        // Element animation
        $item.css(
          utils.prefix({
            transform: "rotateX(180deg)",
            animation: anim +
              " " +
              speed +
              "s " +
              easing +
              " " +
              wait +
              "s 1 normal forwards"
          })
        );

        // Shading animation happens when the next item starts
        if (!last) wait = (index + 1) * time;

        // Shading animation
        $over.css(
          utils.prefix({
            animation: "unfold-over " +
              speed * 0.45 +
              "s " +
              easing +
              " " +
              wait +
              "s 1 normal forwards"
          })
        );
      });

      // Add momentum to the container
      $root.css(
        utils.prefix({
          animation: "swing-out " +
            $kids.length * time * 1.4 +
            "s ease-in-out 0s 1 normal forwards"
        })
      );

      $this.addClass("open");
    },

    // Trigger the fold animation
    close: function(speed, overlap, easing) {
      // Cache DOM references
      $this = $(this);
      $root = $this.find(".root");
      $kids = $this.find(".node").not($root);

      // Establish values or fallbacks
      speed = utils.resolve($this, "speed", speed) * 0.66;
      easing = utils.resolve($this, "easing", easing);
      overlap = utils.resolve($this, "overlap", overlap);

      $kids.each(function(index, el) {
        // Establish settings for this iteration
        anim = "fold" + (!index ? "-first" : "");
        last = index === 0;
        time = speed * (1 - overlap);
        wait = ($kids.length - index - 1) * time;

        // Cache DOM references
        $item = $(el);
        $over = $item.find(".over");

        // Element animation
        $item.css(
          utils.prefix({
            transform: "rotateX(0deg)",
            animation: anim +
              " " +
              speed +
              "s " +
              easing +
              " " +
              wait +
              "s 1 normal forwards"
          })
        );

        // Adjust delay for shading
        if (!last) wait = ($kids.length - index - 2) * time + speed * 0.35;

        // Shading animation
        $over.css(
          utils.prefix({
            animation: "fold-over " +
              speed * 0.45 +
              "s " +
              easing +
              " " +
              wait +
              "s 1 normal forwards"
          })
        );
      });

      // Add momentum to the container
      $root.css(
        utils.prefix({
          animation: "swing-in " +
            $kids.length * time * 1.0 +
            "s ease-in-out 0s 1 normal forwards"
        })
      );

      $this.removeClass("open");
    }
  };

  // Utils
  var utils = {
    // Resolves argument values to defaults
    resolve: function($el, key, val) {
      return typeof val === "undefined" ? $el.data(key) : val;
    },

    // Prefixes a hash of styles with the current vendor
    prefix: function(style) {
      for (var key in style) {
        style[prefix + key] = style[key];
      }

      return style;
    },

    // Inserts rules into the document styles
    inject: function(rule) {
      try {
        var style = document.createElement("style");
        style.innerHTML = rule;
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(style);
      } catch (error) {}
    }
  };

  // Element templates
  var markup = {
    node: '<span class="node"/>',
    back: '<span class="face back"/>',
    over: '<span class="face over"/>'
  };

  // Plugin definition
  $.fn.makisu = function(options) {
    // Notify if 3D isn't available
    if (!canRun) {
      var message = "Failed to detect CSS 3D support";

      if (console && console.warn) {
        // Print warning to the console
        console.warn(message);

        // Trigger errors on elements
        this.each(function() {
          $(this).trigger("error", message);
        });
      }

      return;
    }

    // Fires only once
    if (!initialized) {
      initialized = true;

      // Unfold
      utils.inject(
        "@" +
        prefix +
        "keyframes unfold        {" +
        "0%   {" +
        prefix +
        "transform: rotateX(180deg);  }" +
        "50%  {" +
        prefix +
        "transform: rotateX(-30deg);  }" +
        "100% {" +
        prefix +
        "transform: rotateX(0deg);    }" +
        "}"
      );

      // Unfold (first item)
      utils.inject(
        "@" +
        prefix +
        "keyframes unfold-first  {" +
        "0%   {" +
        prefix +
        "transform: rotateX(-90deg);  }" +
        "50%  {" +
        prefix +
        "transform: rotateX(60deg);   }" +
        "100% {" +
        prefix +
        "transform: rotateX(0deg);    }" +
        "}"
      );

      // Fold
      utils.inject(
        "@" +
        prefix +
        "keyframes fold          {" +
        "0%   {" +
        prefix +
        "transform: rotateX(0deg);    }" +
        "100% {" +
        prefix +
        "transform: rotateX(180deg);  }" +
        "}"
      );

      // Fold (first item)
      utils.inject(
        "@" +
        prefix +
        "keyframes fold-first    {" +
        "0%   {" +
        prefix +
        "transform: rotateX(0deg);    }" +
        "100% {" +
        prefix +
        "transform: rotateX(-180deg); }" +
        "}"
      );

      // Swing out
      utils.inject(
        "@" +
        prefix +
        "keyframes swing-out     {" +
        "0%   {" +
        prefix +
        "transform: rotateX(0deg);    }" +
        "30%  {" +
        prefix +
        "transform: rotateX(-30deg);  }" +
        "60%  {" +
        prefix +
        "transform: rotateX(15deg);   }" +
        "100% {" +
        prefix +
        "transform: rotateX(0deg);    }" +
        "}"
      );

      // Swing in
      utils.inject(
        "@" +
        prefix +
        "keyframes swing-in      {" +
        "0%   {" +
        prefix +
        "transform: rotateX(0deg);    }" +
        "50%  {" +
        prefix +
        "transform: rotateX(-10deg);  }" +
        "90%  {" +
        prefix +
        "transform: rotateX(15deg);   }" +
        "100% {" +
        prefix +
        "transform: rotateX(0deg);    }" +
        "}"
      );

      // Shading (unfold)
      utils.inject(
        "@" +
        prefix +
        "keyframes unfold-over   {" +
        "0%   { opacity: 1.0; }" +
        "100% { opacity: 0.0; }" +
        "}"
      );

      // Shading (fold)
      utils.inject(
        "@" +
        prefix +
        "keyframes fold-over     {" +
        "0%   { opacity: 0.0; }" +
        "100% { opacity: 1.0; }" +
        "}"
      );

      // Node styles
      utils.inject(".node {" + "position: relative;" + "display: block;" + "}");

      // Face styles
      utils.inject(
        ".face {" +
        "pointer-events: none;" +
        "position: absolute;" +
        "display: block;" +
        "height: 100%;" +
        "width: 100%;" +
        "left: 0;" +
        "top: 0;" +
        "}"
      );
    }

    // Merge options & defaults
    var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.makisu.defaults, options);

    // Extract api method arguments
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);

    // Main plugin loop
    return this.each(function() {
      // If the user is calling a method...
      if (api[options]) {
        return api[options].apply(this, args);
      }

      // Store options in view
      $this = $(this).data(opts);

      // Only proceed if the scene hierarchy isn't already built
      if (!$this.data("initialized")) {
        $this.data("initialized", true);

        // Select the first level of matching child elements
        $kids = $this.children(opts.selector);

        // Build a scene graph for elements
        $root = $(markup.node).addClass("root");
        $base = $root;

        // Process each element and insert into hierarchy
        $kids.each(function(index, el) {
          $item = $(el);

          // Which animation should this node use?
          anim = "fold" + (!index ? "-first" : "");

          // Since we're adding absolutely positioned children
          $item.css("position", "relative");

          // Give the item some depth to avoid clipping artefacts
          $item.css(
            utils.prefix({
              "transform-style": "preserve-3d",
              transform: "translateZ(-0.1px)"
            })
          );

          // Create back face
          $back = $(markup.back);
          $back.css("background", $item.css("background"));
          $back.css(utils.prefix({
            transform: "translateZ(-0.1px)"
          }));

          // Create shading
          $over = $(markup.over);
          $over.css(utils.prefix({
            transform: "translateZ(0.1px)"
          }));
          $over.css({
            background: opts.shading,
            opacity: 0.0
          });

          // Begin folded
          $node = $(markup.node).append($item);
          $node.css(
            utils.prefix({
              "transform-origin": "50% 0%",
              "transform-style": "preserve-3d",
              animation: anim + " 1ms linear 0s 1 normal forwards"
            })
          );

          // Build display list
          $item.append($over);
          $item.append($back);
          $base.append($node);

          // Use as parent in next iteration
          $base = $node;
        });

        // Set root transform settings
        $root.css(
          utils.prefix({
            "transform-origin": "50% 0%",
            "transform-style": "preserve-3d"
          })
        );

        // Apply perspective
        $this.css(
          utils.prefix({
            transform: "perspective(" + opts.perspective + "px)"
          })
        );

        // Display the scene
        $this.append($root);
      }
    });
  };

  // Default options
  $.fn.makisu.defaults = {
    // Perspective to apply to rotating elements
    perspective: 1200,

    // Default shading to apply (null => no shading)
    shading: "rgba(0,0,0,0.12)",

    // Area of rotation (fraction or pixel value)
    selector: null,

    // Fraction of speed (0-1)
    overlap: 0.6,

    // Duration per element
    speed: 0.8,

    // Animation curve
    easing: "ease-in-out"
  };

  $.fn.makisu.enabled = canRun;
})(jQuery);

// The `enabled` flag will be `false` if CSS 3D isn't available

if ($.fn.makisu.enabled) {
  var $one_column = $(".one_column");
  var $five_column = $(".five_column");
  var $three_column = $(".three_column");
  var $two_column = $(".two_column");
  var $four_column = $(".four_column");
  // Create Makisus

  $one_column.makisu({
    selector: "dd",
    overlap: 0.85,
    speed: 1.7
  });

  $three_column.makisu({
    selector: "dd",
    overlap: 0.6,
    speed: 0.85
  });

  $five_column.makisu({
    selector: "dd",
    overlap: 0.2,
    speed: 0.5
  });
  $two_column.makisu({
    selector: "dd",
    overlap: 0.4,
    speed: 1
  });
  $four_column.makisu({
    selector: "dd",
    overlap: 0.8,
    speed: 1.2
  });

  // Open all

  $(".list").makisu("open");

  // Toggle on click

  $(".toggle").on("click", function() {
    $(".list").makisu("toggle");
  });

  // Disable all links
} else {
  $(".warning").show();
}
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,700&subset=cyrillic");
html {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  background: #f0f0f0 url("../img/coffee_in_code.jpg") no-repeat top/cover;
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

body:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  opacity: 0.8;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

a {
  -webkit-transition: all 250ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
  -moz-transition: all 250ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
  -ms-transition: all 250ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
  -o-transition: all 250ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
  transition: all 250ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  color: #44311c;
  width: 100%;
  top: 5%;
}

.header h1 {
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  text-shadow: -2px -1px 1px #110d08, 1px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin: 0;
}

.header h2 {
  color: #774c1d;
  text-shadow: 2px 1px 1px #3a250e, 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  margin: 0;
}

.section:after {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  background: #1b1b1b;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

.list {
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-stle: preserve-3d;
  -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -140px;
  top: 20%;
}

.list a {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
}

.list a:hover {
  text-indent: 20px;
}

.list dt,
.list dd {
  text-indent: 10px;
  line-height: 55px;
  background: #E0FBAC;
  margin: 0;
  height: 55px;
  width: 200px;
  color: #fff;
}

.list dt {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0.3px);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(0.3px);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0.3px);
  -o-transform: translateZ(0.3px);
  transform: translateZ(0.3px);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  font-size: 15px;
}

.list dd {
  border-top: 1px dashed rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  line-height: 35px;
  font-size: 11px;
  height: 35px;
  margin: 0;
}

.toggle {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(100px);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(100px);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(100px);
  -o-transform: translateZ(100px);
  transform: translateZ(100px);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin-left: -70px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  background: #026022;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 50px;
  bottom: 10%;
  width: 140px;
  color: #fff;
  left: 50%;
}

.toggle:hover {
  background: #4ab26d;
  color: #000;
}

.warning {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(2px);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(2px);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(2px);
  -o-transform: translateZ(2px);
  transform: translateZ(2px);
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  z-index: 999;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.warning .message {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: -150px;
  margin-top: -60px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  background: #222;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 280px;
  color: #fff;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}

.warning .message h1 {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.one_column dt,
.one_column dd,
.one_column a {
  background: #842e5d;
}

.two_column dt,
.two_column dd,
.two_column a {
  background: #4e2e84;
}

.three_column dt,
.three_column dd,
.three_column a {
  background: #2e845c;
}

.four_column dt,
.four_column dd,
.four_column a {
  background: #84812e;
}

.five_column dt,
.five_column dd,
.five_column a {
  background: #84392e;
}

.one_column a:hover {
  background: #824364;
}

.two_column a:hover {
  background: #58437c;
}

.three_column a:hover {
  background: #4e7c67;
}

.four_column a:hover {
  background: #89865c;
}

.five_column a:hover {
  background: #875c57;
}

.one_column {
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1200px) rotateY(40deg) !important;
  -moz-transform: perspective(1200px) rotateY(40deg) !important;
  -ms-transform: perspective(1200px) rotateY(40deg) !important;
  -o-transform: perspective(1200px) rotateY(40deg) !important;
  transform: perspective(1200px) rotateY(40deg) !important;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 110% 25%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 110% 25%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 110% 25%;
  -o-transform-origin: 110% 25%;
  transform-origin: 110% 25%;
  left: 20%;
}

.two_column {
  -webkit-transform: perspective(900px) rotateY(30deg) !important;
  -moz-transform: perspective(900px) rotateY(30deg) !important;
  -ms-transform: perspective(900px) rotateY(30deg) !important;
  -o-transform: perspective(900px) rotateY(30deg) !important;
  transform: perspective(900px) rotateY(30deg) !important;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 80% 25%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 80% 25%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 80% 25%;
  -o-transform-origin: 80% 25%;
  transform-origin: 80% 25%;
  left: 35%;
}

.three_column {
  -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) translateZ(1px) !important;
  -moz-transform: perspective(600px) translateZ(1px) !important;
  -ms-transform: perspective(600px) translateZ(1px) !important;
  -o-transform: perspective(600px) translateZ(1px) !important;
  transform: perspective(600px) translateZ(1px) !important;
  left: 50%;
}

.four_column {
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1200px) rotateY(-30deg) !important;
  -moz-transform: perspective(1200px) rotateY(-30deg) !important;
  -ms-transform: perspective(1200px) rotateY(-30deg) !important;
  -o-transform: perspective(1200px) rotateY(-30deg) !important;
  transform: perspective(1200px) rotateY(-30deg) !important;
  -webkit-transform-origin: -10% 25%;
  -moz-transform-origin: -10% 25%;
  -ms-transform-origin: -10% 25%;
  -o-transform-origin: -10% 25%;
  transform-origin: -10% 25%;
  left: 65%;
}

.five_column {
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1200px) rotateY(-40deg) !important;
  -moz-transform: perspective(1200px) rotateY(-40deg) !important;
  -ms-transform: perspective(1200px) rotateY(-40deg) !important;
  -o-transform: perspective(1200px) rotateY(-40deg) !important;
  transform: perspective(1200px) rotateY(-40deg) !important;
  -webkit-transform-origin: -10% 25%;
  -moz-transform-origin: -10% 25%;
  -ms-transform-origin: -10% 25%;
  -o-transform-origin: -10% 25%;
  transform-origin: -10% 25%;
  left: 80%;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Leskin Maksim</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header class="header">
    <hgroup>
      <h1>Lesson for weak</h1>
      <h2>best team <br> Quper team</h2>
    </hgroup>
  </header>
  <section class="section">
    <dl class="list one_column">
      <dt>1 week</dt>
      <dd><a href="#">Lesson 01</a></dd>
      <dd><a href="#">Lesson 02</a></dd>
      <dd><a href="#">Lesson 03</a></dd>
      <dd><a href="#">Lesson 04</a></dd>

    </dl>
    <dl class="list two_column">
      <dt>2 week</dt>
      <dd><a href="#">Lesson 05</a></dd>
      <dd><a href="#">Lesson 06</a></dd>
      <dd><a href="#">Hard Lesson 07</a></dd>
      <dd><a href="#">Lesson 08</a></dd>
      <dd><a href="#">Lesson 09</a></dd>

    </dl>
    <dl class="list three_column">
      <dt>3 week</dt>
      <dd><a href="#">Lesson 10</a></dd>
      <dd><a href="#">Lesson 11</a></dd>
      <dd><a href="#">Lesson 12</a></dd>
      <dd><a href="#">Lesson 13</a></dd>

    </dl>
    <dl class="list four_column">
      <dt>4 week</dt>
      <dd><a href="#">Lesson 14</a></dd>
      <dd><a href="#">Lesson 15</a></dd>
      <dd><a href="#">Lesson 16</a></dd>
      <dd><a href="#">Lesson 17</a></dd>

    </dl>
    <dl class="list five_column">
      <dt>5 week</dt>
      <dd><a href="#">Lesson 18</a></dd>
      <dd><a href="#">Lesson 19</a></dd>
      <dd><a href="#">Lesson 20</a></dd>
      <dd><a href="#">Lesson 21</a></dd>
      <dd><a href="#">Lesson 22</a></dd>
    </dl>
    <a href="#" class="toggle">toggle</a>
  </section>
  <div class="warning">
    <div class="message">
      <h1>CSS 3D Не обнаружен</h1>
      <p><a href="www.google.com/chrome" target="_blank">Скачайте браузер который поддерживает CSS 3D анимацию </a></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Думаю скрипты тут не причем, эффект при наведении обеспечивается обычным CSS, возможно именно в firefox ссылки чем-то перекрываются

Comment: У меня fox 61.0.1 работает hover анимация.

Comment: у меня свежая версия на данный момент, hover тоже не работает, хотя он ведь сейчас на том же ядре webkit, что и Chrome и Opera. За последние 2 года не имел проблем с кроссбраузерностью (IE не в счёт)

Comment: Если отключить JS то в firefox работает hover, но анимации естественно нет